# Create Elasticsearch query for product catalog with .Net NEST client

Tags: c#, nest, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-net, elasticsearch-nested

Using the Elasticsearch NEST library for .NET I am trying to create a query that will search for products. The model's structure is the following:

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "product", IdProperty = "ProductId")]
public class ProductIndex
{
    [Number(NumberType.Integer)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Text]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Text]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Number(NumberType.Integer)]
    public int BranchId { get; set; }

    [Number(NumberType.Integer)]
    public int SubbranchId { get; set; }

    [Number(NumberType.Float)]
    public decimal Rating { get; set; }

    [Boolean]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Date]
    public DateTime PublishedAt { get; set; }

    [Nested]
    public ICollection<VariantIndex> Variants { get; set; }
}

[ElasticsearchType(Name = "variant", IdProperty = "VariantId")]
public class VariantIndex
{
    public int VariantId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

I need to filter the products according to the following parameters:

- branchId (int): the product BranchId equals to the branchId
  parameter,
- subbranches (int[]): the product SubbranchId is contained in the
  subbranches array
- rating (int): the product Rating is greater than or equal to the
  rating parameter
- minPrice (int): the product variants Price is greater than minPrice
  parameter
- maxPrice (int): the product variants Price is less than maxPrice
  parameter
- searchTerm (string): the product Name or Description contain the string searchTerm
- tags (string[]): the product variants Values contains one or more or
  all tags.

NOTE: The ***branchId***, ***subbranches***, ***rating*** and ***searchTerm*** should filter out the top level ProductIndex objects. Then, the ***minPrice*** and ***maxPrice*** parameters should filter out any nested Variants objects if their Price is not in the specified range and finally the ***tags*** parameter should filter out any nested Variants object that do not contain any of the tags in their Values array or score them appropriately according to the number of tags that matched in the Values array.

The end result should be a list of scored ProductIndex objects, each containing a list of filtered out and scored VariantIndex objects.

---

Here is how i tried to create the query but this gives me totally wrong search results:

```
Func<SearchDescriptor<ProductIndex>, ISearchRequest> search = s => s
            .From(page * 10)
            .Size(10)
            .Query(q => q
                .Bool(b => b
                    .Must(mu => mu
                        .Match(m => m
                            .Field(f => f.Name)
                            .Query(searchTerm)
                        ), mu => mu
                        .Match(m => m
                            .Field(f => f.Description)
                            .Query(product)
                        ), mu => mu
                        .Terms(t => t
                            .Field(f => f.Variants.Select(v => v.Values))
                            .Terms(tags)
                        )
                    )
                    .Filter(bf => bf
                        .Term(t => t
                        .Field(p => p.BranchId)
                        .Value(mainbranch))
                     )
                    .Filter(bf => bf
                            .Terms(t => t
                            .Field(p => p.SubbranchId)
                            .Terms(subbranches)
                        )
                    )
                    .Filter(bf => bf
                        .Range(r => r
                            .Field(f => f.Variants.Select(v => v.Price))
                            .GreaterThanOrEquals(minPrice)
                            .LessThanOrEquals(maxPrice)
                        )
                    )
                )
            );


        var response = await client.SearchAsync<ProductIndex>(search);
```

---

**EDIT 1:**
Based on the comments my own investigation I finally managed to create a query which works correctly. The only thing left to do is to filter out the list of nested VariantIndex objects so that we only get the variants which comply with the ***price*** and ***tags*** filters. **What code should I add to my latest working version of the query in order to achieve this?**

```
Func<SearchDescriptor<ProductIndex>, ISearchRequest> search = s => s.Type<ProductIndex>()
            .Query(q => q
                .Bool(b => b
                    .Must(m => m
                        .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                            .Query(product)
                            .Fields(f =>
                                f.Fields(f1 => f1.Name, f2 => f2.Description)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    .Should(ss => ss
                        .Match(m => m
                            .Field(f => f.Variants.Select(v => v.Values))
                            .Query(tagsJoined)
                        )
                    )
                    .Filter(m => m
                        .Bool(bl => bl
                            .Must(ms => ms
                                .Range(r => r
                                    .Field(f => f.Rating)
                                    .GreaterThanOrEquals(rating)
                                ),
                                ms => ms
                                    .Range(r => r
                                        .Field(f => f.Variants.Select(v => v.Price))
                                        .GreaterThanOrEquals(minPrice)
                                        .LessThanOrEquals(maxPrice)
                                    )
                            )
                        )

                    )
                )

            )
```

Comment: What results are returned from your current query?

Comment: In the response I get a list of product indexes (List<ProductIndex>) and the problem is that the list contains ProductIndex objects who's BranchId is equal to 5 for example, but In my query the branchId parameter equals to 10. The same is true for all the other properties. The only parameter that is applied correctly is the searchTerm which gives me only the ProductIndex objects that contain that searchTerm in the Description field

Comment: The three `bool` query `filter` clauses should be supplied as arguments to one `.Filter(...)` call, similar to the call to `.Must()`.

Comment: @RussCam I Managed to get a working version of my query, thank you for your suggestion. Please read my EDIT section since there is one more thing left to do with the query.